# Road bike for 6 Foot

Tags: road-bike, bike-fit

I want to buy a bike. I have a bike who may interest me, it is a Tri Bike 51cm. I was wondering if it was OK for me.
I know that for my height 53-56 cm is better but I'm only 115 pounds.
Would that be OK for me?

Comment: 56 even might be too small. My road bike is 58 and I'm 5'11".

Answer (score 4):

A 51cm frame sounds too small for you, assuming you're average limb length for your height.

You can put the saddle up really high, but that makes it a more aggressive body position, and your seat post is not as well embedded in the frame.

You don't mention your age - I'm guessing you may still be growing, in which case the too-small frame will be getting smaller as you grow.

**Answer** Pass on this bike - there will be another.

Answer (score 0):

I am 5'10" and had the use of a 53cm while I decided what to buy. This was clearly too small - had some knee discomfort and felt "bunched up" on the bike. I bought a 58cm and can most definitely feel the difference. My arm may be a little longer than normal, but I am happy with the 58. Don't settle for one that is not the right fit.

Comment: Welcome to [bicycles.se] @larry. As with all new members we recommend that you take the [tour] to make best use of the site, and since you're writing an answer see [answer] also. Good to see you here